# Neo4J - Could not download zip version

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to download neo4j community edition zip version for windows 64 bits. 
But the site (http://www.neo4j.org/download/other_versions) always redirect me to a installer (exe) version.

I am trying http://www.neo4j.org/download/other_versions this link, and then i go in "Binary: zip"
Where can i find the zip version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they've changed the website and forgot the zip version.

To download the zip bundle using the following URL structure:

```
http://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&release=2.1.4&packaging={zip|exe}&architecture={x32|x64}
```

Basicaly you have to remove the `flavour` parameter from the URL.

For the 64 bit Windows version then go for:

http://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&release=2.1.4&packaging=zip&architecture=x64

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be something wrong. 
http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-2.1.4-windows.zip
should work.

Comment: Where did you find this kind of link? Nine years passed and still there is something wrong with http://neo4j.com/download-thanks